# Unity-Tweak-Tool:Theme Not Applying

Tags: unity, unity-tweak-tool

I was playing around with `Compiz` and `unity-tweak-tool` and suddenly unity stopped working, tried restarting but it wasn't effective, reinstalled unity and it started to work normally.

After that, I just noticed that `unity-tweak-tool` is missing. I tried to install it from Software Center and after that tried to change theme but it wasn't working, once again tried to reinstall unity & tweak-tool but it was not effective.

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you mention two consecutive installations without any un-installation. Suggests me that installation is failing. Could you type on your terminal

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

and post us if you observe any errors? It should normally say "already the newest version" and quit.

Comment: Yeah right it's saying that the latest version is already installed.

Comment: So what does "not working" refer to? When you follow @pomba, no GUI appears?

Answer (score 0):

Bring up your terminal by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Just type `unity-tweak-tool` in your terminal and it will bring up  unity-tweak-tool UI.